# x86 Struct scanf

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to convert C to x86. I am using a struct...

```
struct person_record_struct
{
  char last_name[128];
  char first_name[128];
  char year_of_birth[10];
  int month_of_birth; // January => 1
  int day_of_birth; // 1st Day of a Month => 1
  char drivers_license_no[128];
};
typedef struct person_record_struct person_record;
```

I am having trouble getting my scanf to work. Here is the C..

```
result = scanf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%s\n", &records[counter].last_name[0],     

&records[counter].first_name[0], &records[counter].year_of_birth[0],     

&records[counter].month_of_birth, &records[counter].day_of_birth, 

&records[counter].drivers_license_no[0]);
```

And my x86..

```
;counter @ [ebp-4]
;records @ [ebp-16]
; format_string_main_2 db '%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%s\n', 0
; read in info

; push drivers_license_no
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   ;
mov eax, [ebp-4]        
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx                 
add eax, ebx            
lea eax, [eax+276]  
push eax

; push day_of_birth
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   
mov eax, [ebp-4]       
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx            
add eax, ebx            
lea eax, [eax+272]  
push eax

; push month_of_birth
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   
mov eax, [ebp-4]      
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx               
add eax, ebx            
lea eax, [eax+268]  
push ax

; push year_of_birth
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   
mov eax, [ebp-4]      
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx                 
add eax, ebx          
lea eax, [eax+256]  
push eax

; push first_name
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   
mov eax, [ebp-4]        
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx               
add eax, ebx          
lea eax, [eax+128]  
push eax

; push last_name
mov ebx, [ebp-16]   
mov eax, [ebp-4]       
mov ecx, struct_size
mul ecx             
add eax, ebx           
lea eax, [eax+0]       
push eax

push format_string_main_2     
call scanf
add esp, 28
mov [ebp-12], eax
```

I'm using a check to see if result is 6 and if it's not my program that prints an error and exits. It keeps having an error and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

This is my calloc call which appears to be correct...

```
;  // allocate the buffer of all the records
;  records = (person_record *)calloc(number_of_records, sizeof(person_record));

push struct_size
mov eax, [ebp-8]
push eax
call calloc
add esp, 8
mov [ebp-16], eax
```

Comment: Learn to use GDB. It's valuable to any assembly programmer for situations like this. And, what error are you getting?

Comment: Note: It is _very unlikely_ code needs a white-space at the end of a `scanf()` format `"...%s\n"`.  Suggest `"...%s"`.  or better yet `"%127s%127s%9s%d%d%127s"`

Answer (score 0):

Under `month_of_birth` you have `push ax` instead of `push eax`. This would push only the lower 16 bits of the address on the stack, virtually guaranteeing a crash in `scanf`. Fix that and it should be OK.

Comment: I fixed that however it is still tripping my error check...; // if anything doesn't go right, print a simple error and return an error code
;        if (result != 6)
;        {
;          printf("error reading input");
;          return -1;
;        }
cmp dword [ebp-12], 6
je main_for_expr_3

push format_string_main_3
call printf
add esp, 4
mov eax, -1
leave
ret

Comment: could it be my calloc call which is;  // allocate the buffer of all the records
;  records = (person_record *)calloc(number_of_records, sizeof(person_record));

push struct_size
mov eax, [ebp-8]
push eax
call calloc
add esp, 8
mov [ebp-16], eax

Answer (score 0):

There are many weird/wrong things going on in your code.  It will be easier to show a cleaner way.  You have not mentioned the Assembler you are using, there are a few for x86 and each has its own syntax.  Here is how you can do it using NASM:

```
extern printf, scanf, calloc, exit, free, puts
global main

struc person_record
    .last_name           resb    128
    .first_name          resb    128
    .year_of_birth       resb    10
    .month_of_birth      resd    1
    .day_of_birth        resd    1
    .drivers_license_no  resb    128
    .size equ   $ - person_record
endstruc

MAX_RECORDS     equ 2

section .data
Space              db  32, 0
input_format    db "%s%s%s%d%d%s", 0
output_format   db  "%s %s %s %d %d %s", 0

section .text
main:

    push    person_record.size
    push    MAX_RECORDS    
    call    calloc
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    mov     esi, eax
    mov     ebx, eax

    mov     edi, MAX_RECORDS - 1
.FillRecord:    
    lea     eax, [ebx + person_record.drivers_license_no]
    push    eax
    lea     ecx, [ebx + person_record.day_of_birth]
    push    ecx
    lea     edx, [ebx + person_record.month_of_birth]
    push    edx
    lea     eax, [ebx + person_record.year_of_birth]
    push    eax
    lea     ecx, [ebx + person_record.first_name]
    push    ecx
    lea     edx, [ebx + person_record.last_name]
    push    edx
    push    input_format
    call    scanf
    add     esp, 4 * 7

    push    Space
    call    puts
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    add     ebx, person_record.size
    dec     edi
    jns     .FillRecord

    mov     ebx, esi
    mov     edi, MAX_RECORDS - 1
.ShowRecord:    
    lea     eax, [ebx + person_record.drivers_license_no]
    push    eax
    mov     ecx, [ebx + person_record.day_of_birth]
    push    ecx
    mov     edx, [ebx + person_record.month_of_birth]
    push    edx
    lea     eax, [ebx + person_record.year_of_birth]
    push    eax
    lea     ecx, [ebx + person_record.first_name]
    push    ecx
    lea     edx, [ebx + person_record.last_name]
    push    edx
    push    output_format
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4 * 7

    push    Space
    call    puts
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    add     ebx, person_record.size
    dec     edi
    jns     .ShowRecord

    push    esi
    call    free
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    0
    call    exit
```

And the input and output of 2 records:
[image]